# FileOutputStream:Something That I am Missing Out?

Tags: java, arrays, fileoutputstream

I have this program that reads 2 Kb Data from a binary file adds some header to it and then writes it to a new file.
The code is

```
try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(bin);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(bin.getName().replace(".bin",    ".xyz"));
        DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);  
        fos.write(big, 0, big.length);
        for (int n = 1; n <= pcount; n++) {          
            fis.read(file, mark, 2048);
            mark = mark + 2048;             
            prbar.setValue(n);
            prbar.setString("Converted packets:" + String.valueOf(n));
            metas = "2048";
            meta = metas.getBytes();
            pc = String.valueOf(file.length).getBytes();
            nval = String.valueOf(n).getBytes();
            System.arraycopy(pc, 0, bmeta, 0, pc.length);
            System.arraycopy(meta, 0, bmeta, 4, meta.length);
            System.arraycopy(nval, 0, bmeta, 8, nval.length);          
            fos.write(bmeta, 0, bmeta.length);
            fos.flush();
            fos.write(file, 0, 2048);
            fos.flush();
       }
  }catch (Exception ex) {
        erlabel.setText(ex.getMessage());
  }
```

First it should write the header and then the file.But the output file is full of data that does not belong to the file.It is writing some garbage data.What may be the problem?

Comment: DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos); you are not using this stream anywhere

Comment: did you close the fos and fin objects?

Comment: You`re creating a `DataOutputStream` but only use the `FileOutputStream`. This looks like an error (may even be the cause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite clear with some of the declarations missing, but it looks like your problem is with the `fis.read()` method: the second argument is an offset in the byte array, not the file (common mistake).

You probably want to use relative reads.  You also need to check the return value from `.read()` to see how many bytes were actually read, before writing the buffer out.

The common idiom is:

```
InputStream is = ... 
OutputStream os = ...

byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
int len;
while((len = is.read(buf)) != -1)
  os.write(buf, 0, len);

is.close();
os.close();
```

#### Edit

That's a pretty weird way of writing out your metadata, I assume that's what the (unused) `DataOutputStream` is for?

You don't need to keep flushing the output stream, just close it when you're done.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether I have to empty the arrays everytime the loop ends.They have a fixed size

Comment: No, you don't need to clear anything. If `.read(byte[])` tells you that it copied `len` bytes to the array, you can safely write `len` bytes to the output. The single argument version starts writing at index `0` - read the javadoc, it will be more clear.  I'm curious how you allocated `file` in your original code - seems it needs to be at least as large as the original file?

Comment: @Dmitri...Thanks to your suggestion the file has been created.And when I view it in a binary viewer it seems ok,like it should be.But when a program(Written in C) reads the first 60 bytes of the file to get some info,it does not show what it should. eg.instead of 696 it shows 3358.Can this problem be due to data types.

Comment: Could be. I suggest you post your final Java code and your C code as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Dmitri has pointed out, there is something seriously wrong with the way you are writing the metadata.

1. You are writing the metadata every time around the loop, which cannot be right.
2. You are essentially allocating 4 bytes for it, via `"2048".getBytes()`, then copying many more than 4 bytes into it, then writing the 4 bytes. This cannot be right either, in fact it should really be throwing ArrayIndexExceptions at you.
3. It looks as though the metadata is supposed to contain three binary integers. However you are putting String data into it. I suspect you should be using DataOutputStream.writeInt() directly for these fields, without all the `String.valueOf()/getBytes()` and `System.arraycopy()` nonsense.

Comment: But the data has to be written again,before the next 2 kb is written to the file.
I am only writing 4 bytes in the  meta array.
I will try with the data outputstream and then try.

Answer (score 0):

I would like suggest to use `lib` community supported like **apache common-io** for `IO` features.
There are usefule `classes` and `method`;

```
org.apache.commons.io.DirectoryWalker;
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
org.apache.commons.io.IOCase;

FileUtils.copyDirectory(from, to);
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, data);
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(dir);
FileUtils.forceDelete(dir);
```